# Where would I find a Stack Exchange site related to digital logic and basic CPUs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've been looking for a Stack Exchange site for digital logic for a long time. Is there anywhere I can find one?

The Electronics Stack Exchange site seems a bit broad, and the retrocomputing Stack Exchange site is more concerned with other things like microprogramming and microprocessors. Are there any Stack Exchange sites tailored to logic gates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any stack exchanges tailored to logic gates?

No. [SE Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) seems to be the right place.

> The Electronics Stack Exchange seems a bit broad

They have a [digital-logic](/questions/tagged/digital-logic) tag you can use to narrow the scope of your question.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll check retrocomputing for more convoluted questions.

Comment: @TrevorMershon I don't fully understand your comment. May be you could elaborate in your question why you think SE Retrocomputing seems to be more appropriate for your question. Best you would give us an example what kind of question you want to ask, that would make it easier to give you a recommendation for the correct site.

Comment: SE retrocomputing knows a lot about the basic and rudimentary elements of CPUs, but not much about logic gates. SE electronics is the opposite.